# Update a dict with PyMongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I have this kind of document :

```
Doc1{} : 
field1, field2, field3{} :
                field1, field2, field3, field4{}:
                                        4 fields to update.
```

I try with this line but I got 2 issues, the first one is when is updating it's erase all of my fields in field3 and the second is that this line is in the for loop and it's erasing my field but I would like to add.

`db.doc1.update_one({field1 : field1}, {"$set" : {"field3" : {"field4" : content}}})`

Ps : sorry for my approximate English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just update `field4` in `field3`, use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#embedded-documents):

```
record_filter = {'field1' : 'a'}
content = "d"
db.doc1.update_one(record_filter, {"$set" : {"field3.field4" : content}})
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Good to hear! To help the wider community [please upvote and mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).